# Google Map API v3 - (1) Map temporarily flashes bad geocode (2) Add marker click event

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps-api-3

I've managed to trial/error put together a working google v3 api that geocodes an address coming from the database.

Now I"m trying to accomplish two final tasks:

1. The map flashes the original geocode (34.05,-118.24) that is set before the api geocodes the variable I've passed to it.  When I remove this lat/long, the map doesn't work at all.  How can I stop the map from flashing the original lat/long before geocoding the address I've given it?
2. I'd like the user to be able to click the marker and get a result (i.e. "Hello World").  So far with trial and error I have not been able to successfully get the marker to be clickable.

Please help!!  Thanks in advance as always.

```
$address, $city, $state and such are php variables coming from mysql
```

My google script looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
              var geocoder;
              var map;
              function initialize() {
                geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(34.052234,-118.243685);
                var address = '<?php echo $address.', '.$city.', '.$state; ?>';

                var myOptions = {
                  zoom: 14,
                  center: latlng,
                  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                }
                map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
                geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
                  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map, 
                        position: results[0].geometry.location
                    });
                  } else {
                    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                  }
                });
              }


            </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So to make the marker clickable, you need to have an event listener on it.  Also you'll want an infowindow to display your 'hello world'.  This does both, add it into your initialize function.

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map, 
    position: results[0].geometry.location
});

var infowindow =  new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: 'Hello World!',
    map: map
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, this);
});
```

I would also consider doing the geocoding of your address before you create the map, so you can use results[0].geometry.location to set the map center initially.

```
      var geocoder;
      var map;
      function initialize() {
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(34.052234,-118.243685);
        var address = '<?php echo $address.', '.$city.', '.$state; ?>';
        var myOptions = {
          zoom: 14,
          center: latlng,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }

        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            myOptions.center = results[0].geometry.location;

            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map, 
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });

            var infowindow =  new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: 'Hello World!',
                map: map
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.open(map, this);
            });

          } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);

            // just open the map at the default latlng
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
          }
        });
      }
```

Comment: Worked perfectly.  Thanks a million!!